# How to run all TestModule in [Test Setup for Test Modules] CANoe

Tags: python, testing, canoe, com-interface

### My  [Test Setup for Test Modules] same here:

Environment1 (Test_Environment.tse)
-TestEnv1Folder (Folder)

- TestModuleEnv1-1
- TestModuleEnv1-2
  -TestFolder (Folder)

  - TestModuleInFolder1
  - TestModuleInFolder2
    -TestFolder2 (Folder)

    - TestModuleEnv2-1
    - TestModuleEnv2-2

---

I understand use:

```
 test_environment = self.application.Configuration.TestSetup.TestEnvironments.Item("Environment1")
 test_environment = win32.CastTo(test_environment, "ITestEnvironment2")
 testM = test_environment.Folders.Item("TestFolder")
```

and I run Test Module in [TestFolder] folder...
I understand that I have to use p"Folders.Item (index)" in order to run the test Module. (Index will increase gradually).

Question: How can I run the all testModule in all folders(TestEnv1Folder, TestFolder and TestFolder2)?

Comment: What exactly is your question? You seem to know how to iterate over folders and their contents, so what is still open?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ExecuteAll` method under the `TestEnvironment` object. This will execute all the test cases in all the folders under that TestEnvironment.